# What is the difference between ordered tree and rooted tree? - An example

Tags: data-structures, tree

I know the definition of these two types of trees. However, I cannot understand their structures. Could you give me an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rooted Tree has only ONE Element which is considerd as root element.

In the examples below the root element is green and the data structure is represented in form of a binary tree with two child elements.

An Ordered Binary Tree is a form of rooted tree with a specific order.
Started from the root element the smaller number is on the left side and the higher number on the right side.

**Ordered Binary Tree** 
[image]

An Unordered Binary Tree on the other side has no specific order of the elements.

**Unordered Root Tree**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The structure of an unordered tree looks like follows,

[image: An unordered tree]

As can be seen in the above figure, the root of the tree is node A, but its children are not ordered from left to right or in any particular order. However, we can re-draw the tree as follows, in order to make it an ordered rooted tree.

[image: An ordered tree]

An ordered tree can be either a binary tree or else a general tree. The binary nature of a tree and the ordered nature are two separate concepts. The overall idea is, a rooted tree is not an ordered rooted tree unless it is depicted according to a particular order or some additional textual information is given to notify the order.